# icon-youtube didn't work in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, youtube, icons

Here is the code:

```
<div class="social-bar"><a href="http://opensourcehacker.com/"><i class="icon icon-youtube"></i></a></div>
```

I took the code from this link:

```
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/
```

Expect youtube icon, working fine all other icon,

My page look like this http://s1.postimg.org/lna2h903z/Untitled_2.png

May i know why? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of font-awesome are you using

Answer (score 0):

You are using older library for fontawesome. Try updating it.
Instead of

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Use:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then it will work for you.

Comment: OMG, All the icons didn't work when i change the version of css

Comment: You have to update all the css if you are udpating fontawesome. Get the lastest one from same url

Comment: Get the latest version of bootstrap css and js from http://getbootstrap.com/ and for fontawesome you can use the link which I provided in the answer . Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/00g32Lw5/

Comment: Great! You'll need to change this everywhere